# bounds of Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function on the critical line?

Tags: riemann-zeta

I vaguely remembered that

$$0\leq|\zeta(1/2+i t)|\leq C t^{\epsilon},\qquad t>>1,\epsilon>0$$.

Is this bound correct?

Thanks-
mike

Comment: This looks like the [Lindelöf hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis). If it is, it's unproven and follows from the Riemann hypothesis (although weaker).

Comment: @DanielR. Thanks for the information.  This is exactly what I look for. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr01.pdf  pp.97-99 , it is proven that:

$$\zeta(s) < A(d)t^{1-d},  \text{for } \sigma=\mathrm{Re}(s) \geq d,  0 < d < 1  ; t=\mathrm{Im}(s) \geq 1  .$$

with $A(d) = (1/(1-e) + 1 + 3/e)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the reference!

Comment: @mike : this is indeed the upper bound for the $\mu(\sigma)$ function [drawn in red here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_th.C3.A9orie_de_la_fonction_mu) such that $\zeta(\sigma+it) < C(\sigma) (1+|t|^{\mu(\sigma)})$, the Lindelöf hypothesis being to obtain the function in yellow

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks a lot for the comment and the reference!